# Why doesn't flutter catch firebase storage file not found error?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

In my flutter app, I try to get the url of a file in firebase storage. I deleted this file on purpose to test the error message that I display to the user when there is no file found. The problem is Flutter/Dart doesn't catch the error at all! Instead it freezes the application, and in visual studio code it displays this exception:

"Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(download_error, Object does not exist at location., null))"

This is my code to catch the error:

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('nonExistingFile.jpg');
storageReference.getDownloadURL().catchError((onError){
  scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text("Error: File not found!"), duration: new Duration(seconds: 4),));
});
```

The above code DOESN'T catch the error and act accordingly! Why is that??

Comment: There was (is?) a similar issue on AngularFire, you can maybe use the same workaround to fix this: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1736

Comment: StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(); and then you try getting the child, not directly in the reference.